# Using MJPEG Stream as WebGL Texture

Tags: html, three.js, cors, webgl, mjpeg

I need to render an mjpeg steam as a WebGL texture that automatically updates along with the stream.

Using Three.js, I found one approach: drawing the mjpeg stream into an html canvas and using the canvas as the webgl texture:

```
<canvas id="2d" width="512" height="512" style="display: none"></canvas>

<canvas id="3d" width="1000px" height="800px"></canvas>
```

_

```
import THREE from 'three'

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ canvas: document.getElementById('3d') })
let scene, camera

const canvas2d = document.getElementById('2d')
const ctx = canvas2d.getContext("2d")

const img = new Image()
img.crossOrigin = 'anonymous'
img.src = 'http://localhost:8080'

const map = new THREE.Texture(canvas2d)
const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: map })

const init = () => {
    scene = new THREE.Scene()

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(35, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000)
    camera.position.set(0, 0, 5)
    scene.add(camera)

    const geometry = new THREE.TorusGeometry(1, 0.5, 16, 16)
    const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material)
    scene.add(mesh)
}

const animate = () => {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate)

    // Update texture 
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 500, 500)
    map.needsUpdate = true

    renderer.render(scene, camera)
}

init()
animate()
```

This works in Safari but I can't get this to work in Chrome due to what looks like this problem: [Chrome MJPEG CORS "invalid response" when img.crossOrigin="Anonymous"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35506077/chrome-mjpeg-cors-invalid-response-when-img-crossorigin-anonymous) I've tried adding all the proper headers and I've tried a bunch of cors workarounds, but Chrome always thinks that the 2d canvas has been tainted and will not use it as a texture.

---

Is there a better to draw an mjpeg stream into a webgl texture that would work on Chrome as well?

Is there a more direct way to do this all instead of going through an html canvas?

Comment: Is your server sending the [appropriate Access-Control-Allow-Origin header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_enabled_image)?

Comment: @2pha I believe so. I've added `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` and `Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept` This works on Safari and Firefox, but Chrome still marks the 2d canvas as tainted after drawing the mjpeg into it.

Comment: This is a silly check but have you tried clearing your cache, the original header may still be in the cache and tainting your canvas.

Comment: Was there ever any progress made on this? I'm having the same problem.